# DB_HOST and Browser Settings For Laravel App

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm putting together a Laravel 5.2 application and using Homestead with it. When I need to migrate my database these are the settings that I have set up that allows me to do migrate. However if I want to use these in my browswer then I have to switch 127.0.0.1 to localhost. Why do I have to do this and how do I fix that?

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=33060
DB_DATABASE=homestead    
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Anybody have any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find out that I need to keep it as DB_PORT=3306 and only use 33060 for when I'm trying  to access the database with a program like Sequel Pro.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using wamp do  like this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=33060
DB_DATABASE=mysql
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

mysql is your database .you can access it by going localhost/phpmyadmin

Comment: I'm using Homestead as per my original post.